# How to create and authenticate DocuSign users with API integration

Tags: docusignapi

Trying to understand DocuSign API documentation but I'm getting confused - obviously I would like to have a custom built application that allows employees to digitally sign terms and conditions.

Looking at previous questions it looks like I'll need one account to represent the sender (aka "application").  I'm looking to authenticate my application with DocuSign using client credentials and secret but also to include an authorization code to get a user scoped token back from DocuSign.

Looking at the documentation the auth development endpoint is https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token

**Calling the endpoint and getting a user scoped token back**

```
// Header
Authorization Basic <integration_key_and_the_secret>

// Body
grant_type=authorization_code&code=<authorization_code>
```

If I've understood this correctly it means I need to create users beforehand within DocuSign for the process to work, i.e. so when the endpoint above is called with the user email included within the authorization_code value it matches with a user account within DocuSign.

If my understanding is correct then the "Users" endpoint makes sense, i.e. I would need to call the following POST endpoint to create each user that will use my application to sign their terms and conditions.

**Create users endpoint within DocuSign**

```
POST /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users
```

The documentation states I can create multiple users at once although there's a limit for any single request to be no more than 500 users which is ok as my application can be designed to batch users with a number limit included.

Looking for confirmation on whether I've understood the process?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build an app to enable "employees to digitally sign terms and conditions." then the employees will **not** be DocuSign "users." Rather, they will be "Signers."

The OAuth Authorization Code flow you reference in your question enables a DocuSign "user" (also known as a DocuSign "account member") to obtain an access token that can be used with the DocuSign APIs.

In your use case, it sounds like the new employee accesses a web portal (your app) and at some point presses a "Sign the Terms and Conditions" button.

In this flow, the new employee is not (yet) a DocuSign user. So they can't login to DocuSign, they can't use the OAuth Authorization Code flow, etc.

Instead, your application needs to authenticate with DocuSign by itself and then create (via the API) the Signing Ceremony for the new employee.

### How can your application authenticate itself with DocuSign?

The answer for DocuSign eSignature API is that your application will impersonate a DocuSign user via the OAuth JWT grant flow. Most developers create a "system user" such as "HR Department" with email "hr@company.com".

The DocuSign administrator adds the new "system user" to their DocuSign account and your app can then impersonate the user. Remember that the "user" needs to [grant consent to your app](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent) for impersonation.

**Notes**

1. Application authentication is not available for the eSignature API. Your app needs to impersonate a user.
2. If your application hasn't already authenticated the app's user (the new employee) then you need to figure out how to do that. If you want, DocuSign can authenticate someone via SMS messages and many other techniques too.
3. DocuSign has many examples on the Developer Center to assist you with your project.

#### Creating new users in DocuSign

If you really do want to create new users in DocuSign, you can do that via the [Admin API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/). But the rest of your question sounds more like you want the new employees to be DocuSign `Signers` not `Users`

#### Authenticating a Signer

DocuSign offers many features for authenticating a signer. Which authentication methods you choose often depend on the threat model for your agreements, legal requirements, past experiences (in the past, how often were signatures forged or repudiated), value of the agreement (if something goes wrong, did your company lose $10 or $10,000,000) etc.

Some of the authentication options available from DocuSign:

- Machine analysis of the signer's government issued ID
- Liveness detection of the signer
- Online notarization of the agreement
- Email verification (did the signer receive an email?)
- SMS/phone notification (the signer must be able to receive an SMS or phone call at a specific number)
- Shared secret authentication: the human was given a number, later, was the signer able to enter the number into DocuSign as part of the signing ceremony. Or the number is something the real signer already knows, eg their driver license number. -- In this case, the number had to be entered into the DocuSign system for checking
- Knowledge Based Authentication (KBA) -- the signer is asked a series of questions from their credit report (available only in specific countries).

#### Re: authentication via user ID

Yes, a user ID would be a shared secret that DocuSign could check for:

1. Issue the new employee a user ID
2. Enter the user ID into DocuSign as a shared secret for authenticating the signer
3. When the signer signs, they'll be asked to enter the secret. If it matches then the signer has been authenticated.

What to watch out for: how easy is it for someone to guess the new employee's user ID. Remember the problem would happen when a rogue employee violates their agreement with the company and repudiates their signature, saying they never signed it.

If your employee user ids are known within the company or easy to guess then it may not be beyond a reasonable doubt that the rogue employee actually did not sign their agreement (even though they did).

In this case the employee would be claiming that their signature was forged, where the reality is that they repudiated their real signature.

This type of example is why signer authentication is so important.

### Added: my app authenticates its users. Do I need DocuSign authentication too?

If you, the application developer, build an application that authenticates its users then you may or may not need additional authentication by DocuSign.

Example:

1. You build an application
2. In order to use the application, your users must authenticate to the app. Eg, sign in using OAuth to the application
3. Then, as part of the application, the user presses the "sign contract" button. At this point your application creates a DocuSign envelope and uses the [EnvelopeViews:createRecipient](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/) API call to create the Signing Ceremony. As part of the API call, your app can specify how it **already** authenticated the signer. When you redirect the signer to the signing ceremony, no additional authentication is done.
4. On the other hand, suppose the contract is extremely valuable and your business person is concerned that the authentication credentials used for signing into your app are not strong enough. In this case, your app, when it creates the envelope, can require additional authentication.

### Why use the Admin API to create users if signers aren't users?

The admin api is used to for many actions including creating new users within a DocuSign account. Only users can send envelopes. If an employee will need to send envelopes then a new user account can be created for the new employee either manually or programmatically via the Admin API.

Comment: ok so if I understand correctly I can create a single account as a "system user" which is used for API authentication, this account can then have an email of "hr@company.com" for example.  The new employee is a "signer" rather than a "user" which means they do not need their own DocuSign account.  If that's correct how do I identify the signer?  I see documentation that says SMS or email but can it be a user ID?  thanks

Comment: You're correct. Re signer authentication--I've added to my answer

Comment: added info about using a user id for signer authentication

Comment: thanks for this great information.  The challenge I'm seeing is that my app will have security measures in place i.e. SSO, role-based access control etc for the employee to get to the DocuSign integration bit so the authentication options you've kindly listed by DocuSign will not be provided.

Comment: also, if "signers" (i.e. employees) do not need a user account then why would you create users via Admin API in the first place?  I assume the benefit is that if my integration creates user accounts (via the Admin API) it means my app can authenticate as the employee, i.e. an employee scoped token (rather than just the system "HR" account?)

Comment: See my added info in the answer.

Comment: Only create new DocuSign users if they will be senders. Don't create them as a sender just for one envelope that they'll be signing. Please ask a new question on StackOverflow if you have more questions about this.